# Why Class name appended with _private.h word

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an existing code where i can see, ClassName.h,ClassName.m and ClassName_private.h, here i have doubt that whats the use of having ClassName_private.h.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Presumably lists those methods defined by `ClassName` that are are called by other parts of the library but are not meant to be called from outside the library. (I assume you are looking at existing code for a library where this naming style would make some sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some developers will use this pattern of setting up a category like you described to mimic `protected` and `private` behavior like you can see in other languages (such as C++). You import the private header into classes you think should have access to those methods. This allows you to only expose those methods to certain classes.